# Response data truncation when running SP through job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

**Subject:**

I've got a report that I create every month. The creation of report consists of 2 steps:

1. Get an XML from our service and store it in DB;
2. Parse XML and create file.

For the last few month I've created report in manual mode. And now I want to automate this stuff.
But here comes a

**Problem:**

The second step (parsing XML and file creation) runs like a charm, but with first step I'm observing weird behaviour.

I got Stored Procedure which gets XML:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Structure].[GetXML]
    @LastActDate date,
    @CurActDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    begining:

    DECLARE @URI varchar(2000),
            @methodName varchar(50),
            @objectID int,
            @hResult int,
            @setTimeouts nvarchar(255),
            @serv nvarchar(255) = 'http://example.com/docs/',
            @result nvarchar(max) = ''

    DECLARE @t TABLE(Resp nvarchar(max))

    declare @timeStamp nvarchar(50) = convert(nvarchar(50),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,127)

    declare @CurDate date = dateadd(day,0,getdate())

    --EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @objectID OUT
    EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @ObjectID OUT

    SELECT  @URI = @serv + '.newchange?ds='+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@LastActDate,104)+'&df='+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@CurActDate,104)+'&pardaily=1',
            @methodName='GET',
            @setTimeouts = 'setTimeouts(9000,90000,900000,9000000)' 

    EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false' 
    EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, @setTimeouts
    EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null 

    INSERT INTO @t
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText'

    SELECT top 1 @result = Resp 
    FROM @t

    if @result is null
    begin
        delete from @t
        exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID
        exec sp_OADestroy @objectID 
        goto begining
    end
    else
    begin
        INSERT INTO Structure.MonthlyRow 
        SELECT @timeStamp, @result 
    end
END
```

When I run this SP like

```
EXEC [Structure].[GetXML] '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01'
```

I got a row in `Structure.MonthlyRow` table with correct `timestamp` and `response` (the average length is ~70k symbols)

Here is creation script of a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Structure.MonthlyRow(
    [timestamp] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [RowResp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dDayly] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([timestamp] DESC))
```

If I create a job that launch this SP I get a row in table with results, and the length of result is **512 symbols**! It is a proper part of XML that looks like it was truncated from `nvarchar(max)` to `nvarchar(512)`, but I have no variables or table columns with length of 512 that are used.

**What have I tried:**

1. *Run as user* with my account in Job Step properties;
2. Job was started by schedule or manually;
3. Add `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` in SP;
4. Tried using `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` and `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`.

**Question:**

What possibly could be a problem? Why I am getting correct results when I run my SP manually, and got only 512 symbols of response when run SP as job step?

**Note:**

Yes, I know that getting XML from web-service is better handled by PHP, C# or even PowerShell and if I can not find a solution I will use one of them.

Comment: Maybe you could try to check what's happening on the network with a tool like Network Monitor or Wireshark? See if the request are the same

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add this line at the top of your sp or in the job before `EXEC` of your sp

```
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;
```

the problem is that jobs set a default

```
SET TEXTSIZE 1024
```

this limits data returned to 1024 chars (512 for **n**chars)

Comment: a big thanks to you +1 really i was facing this issue and get resolved from your answer. perfect one stay blessed!!!!

Comment: @Haseeb I got crazy myself with this problem :)

Comment: 2022, i was going nuts trying to get why my query worked on SSMS and not on task scheduler. 

Comment: You saved my life, today in 2023.