# sp_executesql or exec(@var) is too long. Maximum length is 8000

Tags: sql-server-2005, varchar, sp-executesql, large-data

I have large queries
so i cant use linked server in production by rules.
i pass a `varchar(max)` which this has more than 8000 characters.

but `sp_executesql` does not support more than 8000 characters then how can i execute my string?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated

Comment: problem is not with @var or type nvarchar(max) problem is with sp_executesql, which only support 8000 characters

Comment: You may need to create views to move some of the statement outside the query if the restriction is in the stored procedure parameter.

Answer (score 4):

`nvarchar(max)` should work on SQL Server 2008 or later.

Does this work?:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'select' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),REPLICATE(' ', 8000)) + ' ''Above 8000 character limit test'''
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

If you're using a version before that, you may need to split the query into multiple variables:

[How to use SQL string variable larger than 4000 character in SQL server 2005 Stored Procedure?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c26b1e1e-5900-43da-b462-02b1550bcfc3/how-to-use-sql-string-variable-larger-than-4000-character-in-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure)

Comment: problem is not with @var or type nvarchar(max) problem is with sp_executesql, which only support 8000 characters

Comment: Hmm... does the following code work in your SQL?

Edit: Having some errors pasting the code here. I'll message it to you.

Comment: which code? have  something as it declare @x nvarchar(max)   set @x='select 1 number union all select 2 as number union all select 3 as number '(etc until this get more than 8000 caracters), this work if the length of @x is less to 8000 but when this is more then 8000 this does not work, and i got "is too long. Maximum length is 8000"

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: is it diferent at other versions? i am using 2005

Comment: I think 2005 works a little differently from what I've read. One person suggests using "exec" instead on this link: http://sqlmag.com/stored-procedures/character-limitation-spexecutesql

Comment: then is it imposible execute more then 8000 characters? is there not a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try  to  declare something like

```
declare  @var_1 nvarchar(4000);
declare  @var_2 nvarchar(4000);
         .
         .
         .
declare @var_n nvarchar(4000);
```

so you do something like this

```
exec(@var_1 + @var_2 + ....+ @var_n)
```

Hope that this will help you

Comment: problem is not with variable, problem is with Exec apparently could receive only 8000 characters, then if i need execute a larger string, how can i execute?

Comment: This is really old I don't know if is still relevant but have a look http://sqlmag.com/stored-procedures/character-limitation-spexecutesql

Comment: Sorry this solution does not work