# "String or Binary Data Would be Truncated" Error when using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to SQL to insert data into a table, but get an SqlException saying that "String or binary data would be truncated". However, the table only consists of two GUIDs, which have an exact size; and a nvarchar(max), and my strings are less than 20 characters.

I tried inserting rows by hand, using SqlCmd, and this worked fine. I also verified using SQL Profiler that nothing gets written tot the trace, indicating the problem is coming from the Linq to SQL framework.

The table definition is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results](
    [GroupID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupID, ItemID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And the Linq to SQL mapping (from the DBML file) is:

```
<Table Name="dbo.Results" Member="Results">
  <Type Name="Result">
    <Column Name="GroupID" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
    <Column Name="ItemID" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
    <Column Name="Name" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(MAX) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
  </Type>
</Table>
```

And in my C# code, this gives the exception:

```
db.Results.InsertOnSubmit(new Result
{
    GroupID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ItemID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "test"
});
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand exactly what's going on here; looks like a bad Linq to SQL mapping, or (unlikely) a bug in the framework.

But to get around this, I replaced:

```
db.Results.InsertOnSubmit(new Result
{
    GroupID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ItemID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "test"
});
db.SubmitChanges();
```

With:

```
string cmd = string.Format("insert into Results values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), "test")
db.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
```

And this works (not just with the test string, but with the actual data).

Still curious to understand what's causing the exception with the original code...

Answer (score 0):

I found this which is a question about nvarchar(max) being truncated. Possibly the answer to that issue will fix yours. It might be misunderstanding but I hope it helps.
It's a different issue but both are about nvarchar(max) being truncating so...

[nvarchar(max) still being truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated)