# Nvarchar(max) shrinks to 4000 chars in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a dynamic query in stored procedure, and when I try to print that dynamic query, it only prints a part of the whole query.

My variable that holds the whole dynamic query is declared like below

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

When I print the variable's length like below, It gives the length of the whole query, which is good.

```
PRINT LEN(@SQL)
```

But, when I print the script itself, It prints only a part of the whole query.

```
PRINT @SQL
```

I also tried to print it like below

```
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@SQL)
```

Why it only prints first 4000chars? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not read the docs? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode string. Longer strings are truncated. The varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types are truncated to data types that are no larger than varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, but my string is around 15.000 chars,

Comment: Your data isn't being shrunk/truncated.  SSMS has a limit to how many characters it will display for certain fields.  Using another application to interpret the `SELECT` query results will yield the full value of the field.

Comment: `Why it only prints first 4000chars?` Because this is how `PRINT` works, which is written in the docs very clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nvarchar(max) still being truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The Print command is limited to outputting 4000 characters (see BOL - Books Online, for more details). It does not mean nvarchar(max) has shrunk to 4000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

try as below to print entire string,

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT ....' [Up To 4,000 characters, then rest of statement as below]

SET @Query = @Query + [rest of statement]

Now run your query as normal i.e. EXEC ( @Query )
```

got the answer from below link

[nvarchar(max) still being truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated)

Answer (score 2):

It's PRINT that is limited to 4000 characters, not the NVARCHAR(MAX) variable.

A workaround would be to just something like this PRINT BIG function with your string if you want to output everything.

https://www.richardswinbank.net/doku.php?id=tsql:print_big

You could also just SELECT the variable which isn't limited and copy the contents from the results.