# Execute a query string as part of a hard-coded statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very long stored procedure that runs a select statement. The statement I would like to add at the end would work in a query string. Is it possible to execute a query string as part of a hard-coded statement in SQL Server?

```
SELECT * 
FROM INV_DATA 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND MY_ID = 

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT id FROM people WHERE id = 
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT ... WHERE storeID = (CASE WHEN ...@ACT_METHOD = ...)) AND ...'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you really need dynamic SQL. Where does `@ACT_METHOD` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible the way you are trying to do it.

Another way to achieve the same result would be:

1. I am assuming , the last statement you want to add to existing procedure must have some dynamic criteria but it will always return a list of IDs.
2. So write a dynamic SQL to select all Ids and put the result in a temp table.

`Declare @sql varchar(2000) @sql = ''Select Id from ....'`. -- put your query which you want to add to procedure here.

```
Create table #temp ( Id int)

Insert into #temp Exec(@sql)
```

3. Now use this #temp table as a join to existing select query in proc.

```
Select *
From INV_DATA a
Join #temp b On a MY_ID = b.id
Where 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a built-in stored procedure that runs queries into string variables, `sp_executesql`.

Here's an exemple:

```
DECLARE @IntVariable INT;  
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);  
  
/* Build the SQL string one time.*/  
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT BusinessEntityID, NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, LoginID  
       FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee   
       WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@BusinessEntityID tinyint';  
/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 197;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;  
/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 109;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```

[SQL Server `sp_executesql` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What if the current query string would be over 8,000 characters, would Sql Server make some adjustment for that?

Comment: i think the problem is in your string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated try to split your string into some others and concatenate when pass to `sp`.

You can create some views and stored procedures in order to reduce your "main" code.