# MS Access - SQL query - NVARCHAR(MAX) is cut off when using DISTINCT keyword in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server connected to an Access frontend. Some text fields are set to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and are working fine when I use direct table access to them.

For a query I needeed a `LEFT JOIN` to get access to a `WHERE` clause on fields of the other table so I created something like this:

```vba
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT dbo_tbl_Changes.Change_Nr, dbo_tbl_Changes.Title, dbo_tbl_Changes.ChangeContent, dbo_tbl_Changes.Date
FROM dbo_tbl_Changes LEFT JOIN dbo_tbl_Parts ON dbo_tbl_Changes.Change_Nr = dbo_tbl_Parts.Change_Nr
WHERE dbo_tbl_Parts.PartType = 'bolt'
ORDER BY dbo_tbl_Changes.Date DESC "

Forms![frm_ChangeOverview].RecordSource = strSQL
Forms![frm_ChangeOverview].Requery
```

With this, the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field `ChangeContent` is getting cut off and not showing all its content.

**If I leave out the `DISTINCT` keyword, the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is correctly working** within the form in a RichText field.
But then I will get more results than I wawnt (doubled entries) as I need the `DISTINCT` keyword in that query to remove those doubled (or even more) results.

One example: The ChangeContent has 1441 characters and is truncated to 157 characters but only when I use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

I'm using the native SQL ODBC driver as no other can be installed in my environment.

What could be the issue?

Comment: It looks like you have the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated. If not, please describe it in a little more detail.

Comment: @Jesusbrother this could be similar, whereas the truncated entries do have much less than those 4000 characters. And as I'm not writhing a dynamic query whthin the SQL server, I cannot figure out how to use this "CAST" statement in my case to try it out.

Comment: You could also try to use a **Pass-Through query** as record source for your form (and edit it's SQL on the fly). That won't have this problem. It will be read-only, but the current one will be too (I think).

Comment: @Andre: But how to do this? I cannot find a good example how to "dynamically" change the RecordSource of my form when using a pass-through query. How to set something like Forms![frm_ChangeOverview].RecordSource = PassThorugh Query?

Comment: I found it out now - using the Pass-Through query was a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and is because Access reads the field as a *Long Text* (memo) field. However, Access can only apply `Distinct` on 255 characters or less.

You may have to look up the full record afterwards, for example from this old example:

```vb
Public Function LookupMemo( _
  ByVal strSource As String, _
  ByVal strFieldID As String, _
  ByVal strFieldMemo As String, _
  ByRef lngID As Long, _
  ByRef varMemo As Variant) _
  As String

' Extracts without truncation to 32768 characters the 
' content of a memo field in a query.
'
' Assumes proper wrapping of table/field names containing spaces 
' like "[My field name]" and a single field unique numeric key.
'
' Typical usage (SQL):
'
'   SELECT
'     ID,
'     LookupMemo("Table1", "ID", "MemoField", [ID], [MemoField]) AS FullMemo
'   FROM
'     Table1;
'
' 2003-12-29. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  ' Maximum length of string from memo field when retrieved in a query.
  Const clngStrLen  As Long = &H8000&

  Dim strExpr       As String
  Dim strDomain     As String
  Dim strCriteria   As String
  Dim strMemo       As String
  Dim lngLen        As Long
  
  On Error GoTo Exit_LookupMemo

  If Not IsNull(varMemo) Then
    lngLen = Len(varMemo)
    If lngLen < clngStrLen Then
      ' The memo field is not truncated.
      strMemo = varMemo
    ElseIf Len(strSource) > 0 And Len(strFieldID) > 0 And Len(strFieldMemo) > 0 Then
      ' The memo is probably truncated by the query.
      ' Lookup the full memo in strSource.
      strExpr = strFieldMemo
      strDomain = strSource
      strCriteria = strFieldID & " = " & lngID & ""
      strMemo = vbNullString & DLookup(strExpr, strDomain, strCriteria)
    End If
  Else
    ' Return empty string.
  End If
  
  LookupMemo = strMemo

Exit_LookupMemo:
  Exit Function
  
Err_LookupMemo:
  ' Return empty string.
  Resume Exit_LookupMemo
  
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I integrate this in my query? If I use it it will give me the text result of the one ID but how to include this in my query so can use this as a RecordSource? I edited my question to show how I use it.

Comment: That depends. As shown in the in-line comment, but you have no unique ID, so you may change from `Distinct` to `Group By` and then use `First([ID])` or similar to pick a record to display.

Comment: I did not find it out - what do you mean with "it depends"? As soon as I use "DISTINCT" again with the function, it will again truncate the data even in the ChangeContentMemo field which I created with your function example.

Comment: And when trying to use "Group by" it gives me an error that the LookupMemo function is not part of an aggregate function

Comment: _Depends_ means that I don't have your data, neither the desired output. You may need to use a second query using the one you have as source and then implement the `LookupMemo` in the second query.

Comment: I now solved it by using a pass-through query like @Andre suggested.