# Concatenating SQL Server VARCHAR(N), results with unexpected and inconsistent truncated results when converted to NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, implicit-conversion, string-concatenation, varchar

In the following code we see that concatenation of varchar(n) where n>4000, results with unexpected and inconsistent truncated results when converted to nvarchar(max):

1. When only varchar(n) values are involved in the concatenation the result is truncated to 8000 chars.
2. A sequence of varchar(n) concatenations, which is done prior to a concatenation to an nvarchar(max), is truncated to 4000 chars, before it is concatenated to the nvarchar(max).
3. A sequence of varchar(n) concatenations, which is done after a concatenation to an nvarchar(max), each varchar(n) is truncated to 4000 chars before it is concatenated

I guess that the implicit cast is done in order of concatenation, but then I would say that (1) behave as expected, (2) should be truncated to 8000 and (3) should not be truncated at all.

It seems like there is some kind of a (wrong) length cast to 4000 that is done out of the concatenation order which is somehow related to the resulting type NVARCHAR. But then if the intention was to cast all the concatenations according to the resulting type, then, since it is MAXed, no truncates would have been expected (which would give the best result).

Where am I wrong?

```
DECLARE @x AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @y AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_10 chars_'
DECLARE @z AS VARCHAR(4200) = replicate('_', 4200)

SET @x = @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4200'

SET @x = @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8400 = 4200 * 2'

SET @x = @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12600 = 4200 * 3'


SET @x = @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4210 = 4200 + 10'

SET @x = @z + @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8410 = 4200 * 2 + 10'

SET @x = @z + @z + @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12610 = 4200 * 3 + 10'


SET @x = @y + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4210 = 10 + 4200'

SET @x = @y + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8410 = 10 + 4200 * 2'

SET @x = @y + @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12610 = 10 + 4200 * 3'


SET @x = @z + @z + @z + @y + @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 25210 = 4200 * 3 + 10 + 4200 * 3'
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833549/nvarcharmax-still-being-truncated) answer your question?

Comment: (1) behaves as expected.. for (2) the addition of varchars will be varchar(8000) according to (1). Then this varchar(8000) is added to nvarchar, implicit conversion of varchar->nvarchar (data precedence) , varchar(8000)->nvarchar(4000) + nvarchar(max). For (3) each individual varchar(8000) is implicitly converted to nvarchar(4000) as it is added to the nvarchar of the previous addition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate two `varchar` values together, the resulting length of the data type is the sum of the two, **up to a maximum of 8000**, any longer will be truncated.

When you concatenate two `nvarchar` values together, the resulting length of the data type is the sum of the two, **up to a maximum of 4000**, any longer will be truncated.

Only when you store it in a `max` variable does the value become `max`, the truncation will happen before then

Furthermore, you have a second implicit conversion going on here, from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, which itself causes truncation because `nvarchar` can only be up to 4000.

If you concatenate a `nvarchar` and a `varchar`, the `varchar` is converted to match, but capped at 4000. The final result will not become `max` until it is stored in the variable. So the implicit conversion will be done *after* that truncation.

Your results now make perfect sense:

- The length is already 4200, and is extended to `max`.

```sql
SET @x = @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4200'
```

---

- In these cases, the intermediate value is capped at 8000, and only *then* converted to `max`

```sql
SET @x = @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8400 = 4200 * 2'

SET @x = @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12600 = 4200 * 3'
```

---

- In these cases, an implicit conversion to `nvarchar` is done first, then concatenated with a `max` *afterwards*, so the original `@z` value was truncated first.

```
SET @x = @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4210 = 4200 + 10'

SET @x = @z + @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8410 = 4200 * 2 + 10'

SET @x = @z + @z + @z + @y
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12610 = 4200 * 3 + 10'

SET @x = @y + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 4210 = 10 + 4200'

SET @x = @y + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 8410 = 10 + 4200 * 2'

SET @x = @y + @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 12610 = 10 + 4200 * 3'

SET @x = @z + @z + @z + @y + @z + @z + @z
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 25210 = 4200 * 3 + 10 + 4200 * 3'
```

The only way to guarantee the right results is to cast your values to `nvarchar(max)` *first*

```sql
SET @x = CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max)) + CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max)) + CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max)) + @y + CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max)) + CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max)) + CAST(@z AS nvarchar(max))
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 25210 = 4200 * 3 + 10 + 4200 * 3'
```

Alternatively, just use `CONCAT`, which deals with all of this correctly anyway

```sql
SET @x = CONCAT(@z, @z, @z, @y, @z, @z, @z);
print CAST(len(@x) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '    Expected 25210 = 4200 * 3 + 10 + 4200 * 3'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qxBpgNBh)

Comment: or use concat()

Comment: Good point have modified

Comment: From your answers it seems that SQL Server string concatenation operator (+) simply does not implicitly convert [n]varchar(n) -> [n]varchar(max). This is so odd...

Comment: It does, it's just that that happens in a separate step, after converting from `varchar` to `nvarchar`. And that first conversion will not upgrade to `max`, hence the truncation because `nvarchar` cannot be more than 4000. Note that if `@z` was an `nvarchar(4000)` or less value to start with then it would work fine https://dbfiddle.uk/VsWs1vGx